# Simplifying $\cos(x) \times \cos(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I got a problem wrong on my homework because I simplified $\cos (x) \times \cos (y)$ to be $\cos (xy)$, and my teacher wrote on my paper that it can't be simplified. I was wondering if anyone could give me an explanation as to why you can't simplify those two.

Comment: Because that equation would have to be true for all real numbers $x,y$. In particular it must be true for $0, \pi$. Yet,  $$\cos(0)\cos(\pi) \neq \cos(0 \cdot \pi)=\cos(0)$$

Comment: I assume your teacher meant only that $\cos (x) \times \cos (y)$ can’t be simplified the way you simplified it, because $\cos (x) \times \cos (y)= \cos x \cos y$ is not an identity. The product $\cos (x) \times \cos (y)$ is equal to various things, but $\cos(xy)$ is not one of them, and none of them is arguably “simpler.”

Comment: Try graphing $\cos(x)\cos(y)$ and $\cos(xy)$. You'll see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

It is depends what you mean by saying simplify...
Sometimes it can be useful to use this identity:
$\cos(x) \cos(y) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos(x+y) + \cos(x-y)\right]$
Usually you can change trigonometric function multiplication to sum or backwards.

Multiplication of any two functions with different variables cannot be simplified into one function of one variable. 
This kind of simplification is extremely rare:

(1) $f(x)f(y)=g(xy)$

Examples of function that fulfill (1) is $f(x)=ax$ or $f(x)=ax^n$.
Other function that fulfill (1) probably esoteric...

Comment: Why do you have $f$ on the LHS and $g$ on the right?  I think you mean $x^a$, not $ax$.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you allow arbitrary functions on the RHS then $ax$ is by no means the *only* differentiable solution as you claim.  What about $f(x) = ax^n$?

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Comment: If $f(x) = ax$, then $f(x)f(y) = axay = a^2 xy$, but $f(xy) = axy$, so isn't that not actually an example of the property you're talking about? I agree with the above commenter that $f(x) = x^a$ is a good example. Since $x^a y^a = (xy)^a$

Comment: yes, but $g$ not have to be equal $f$